Безопасен ли GoodbyeDPI?
Все знают про замедление Ютуба и наверно слышали про такую вещь как GoodbyeDPI. Я знаю метод про дискорд, но хотел узнать, безопасна ли эта программа? Не будет с ней таких проблем как в ВПН по типу слив данных и т.д? И безопасно ли она будет для ПК в целом?

Чисто технически GoodbyeDPI в отличии от прокси/впн решений трафик никуда не гонит и в сеть вообще не лезет. Вся его функция сводится к тому, чтобы немного изменять исходящие пакеты, чтобы обмануть DPI фильтр, и фильтровать входящие, чтобы обнулить работу того же фильтра, в случае когда обмануть его не выходит.

Я бы не стал устанавливать GoodbyeDPI на серьёзную машину, на которой множество конфиденциальных данных, особенно на рабочий компьютер/ноутбук с доступом в корпоративную сеть. Причин несколько:

Я не профессиональный программист вообще и на C в частности;
Код использует UB и математику с указателями, потому что в C иначе не получается — куча пространства для ошибок;
Программа не проходила аудита кода даже моими глазами;
Драйвер WinDivert не проходил аудита кода и периодически вызывает несовместимости с другими драйверами с BSOD'ами (даже если ошибка не непосредственно в WinDivert).
Программа была написана по приколу, чтобы потренироваться в фильтрации пакетов на Windows. Я не пользуюсь Windows чёртову дюжину лет. Иными словами, я очень нерегулярно сам использую GoodbyeDPI.

Что может произойти?

В программе найдут уязвимость, связанную с обработкой данных в пакете, с переполнением буфера, с возможностью эксплуатации на стороне сервера ⇒ вам прогрузят код с привилегиями SYSTEM, украдут все данные и заразят компьютер.
В драйвере WinDivert найдут аналогичную уязвимость ⇒ вам прогрузят код с привилегиями ядра, украдут все данные и заразят компьютер потенциально так, что антивирусы не обнаружат заражение.

Это всё применимо к совершенно любой программе в целом, но к GoodbyeDPI в этом плане стоит относиться особенно настороженно, т.к. и сама программа, и драйвер запущены с максимальными привилегиями, а код и того, и другого написан любителями.
До сих пор периодически пишут об ошибках запуска на необновленных Windows 7 c MS17-010, на таких системах потенциальные проблемы от GoodbyeDPI вообще не имеют никакого значения — вас куда быстрее проэксплуатируют через другой десяток уязвимостей :D

Такой ерунды я ещё не читал. Причем здесь UB, если у вас в голове не укладывается работа арифметики с указателями или ещё чем-то я то это уж ваши проблемы...

Код использует UB — это довольно сильное утверждение. А пруфы будут?

Какая-то странная ситуация в комментариях - возникли сомнения в том, что автор программы понимает как она работает?)

:) Хотел поспорить, но потом обратил внимание на ник...

Господа,всем спасибо за ваши ответы на мой вопрос!

О, спасибо за софтину и обновки, уникальная и бесценная штуковина! А что по поводу WinDivert, который например используется в WireShark? Я к тому что есть же вроде некустарные решения драйвера и давно, или там другое?

@aepot, нет, там npcap, он только захватывает пакеты.

Да, безопасна. Принцип работы программы логичный и понятный. Исходный код открыт и проверен многими людьми.
